# Algorithm to return number of solutions from sudoku grid

Tags: java, np-complete

I'm trying to implement a sudoku library. I did generator and now I'm doing solver and one of the functions is to check uniqueness of grid (Returns a number of available solutions, more than 1 - no Unique solution).
I got stuck on this recursion function and I can't return number just print the grids...

```
public static void checkSolutionsNum (Grid grid_) {

    Grid grid = new Grid(grid_); //Makes copy of the the grid .
    int size = grid.getSize(); //Gets the size of the grid.

    Cell cell = grid.getNextEmptyCell();

    if (cell == null) { //Grid is full.
        System.out.println(grid);
    }


    else {
        for (int num = 1 ; num <= size ; num++) {
            cell.setValue(num);
            if (Checker.isAvailableNumberInCell(cell,grid)){
                checkSolutionsNum(grid)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the current algorithm I have. I want it to return a number of solutions available and not print the solutions.

Comment: Note : you are actually not required to know howmany solutions exist. You are only required to stop if you find more than one. That will save a lot of computation.